# Child class with same name

Tags: css, html, less, media-queries

I'm not too sure if this is a problem or whether it can even be done. I'm not even sure on what I should google to find out whether it can be done/how it can be done.

What I want to do is have a child class with the same class selector as it's parent. I've done this in Less and CSS (see below), but I don't think it is the cleanest way to do it. Is there a better or cleaner way to "re-use" the class selector?

The selectors in question are

```
.r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10 { ... }
```

I've got the following Less code

```
.r-slide-right-10 {
    @media @default-media-small {
        .SlideUp(75);
        .r-slide-right-10 {
            .SlideUpNoOffset(75);
        }
    }
    @media @default-media-medium, @default-media-large {
        .SlideRight(10);
        .r-slide-right-10 {
            .SlideRightNoOffset(10);
        }
    }
}
```

which generates the following CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em ) {
  .r-slide-right-10 {
    height: 75vh;
    bottom: -76vh;
  }
  .r-slide-right-10.r-active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -75vh);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -75vh);
    transform: translate(0, -75vh);
  }
  .r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10 {
    height: 75vh;
    bottom: -75vh;
  }
  .r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10.r-active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -75vh);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -75vh);
    transform: translate(0, -75vh);
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em ), only screen and (min-width: 64.063em ) {
  .r-slide-right-10 {
    width: 10vw;
    right: -11vw;
  }
  .r-slide-right-10.r-active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
    transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
  }
  .r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10 {
    width: 10vw;
    right: -10;
  }
  .r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10.r-active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
    transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: If this works I wouldn't worry about it, but if these are always first level children, you may want to consider using the ">" css selector.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that the classes are the same, it's still a child of the parent so the LESS/corresponding CSS is as I would expect in this scenario.

Comment: It does work as I intend, and I don't expect the CSS to be any cleaner. But I was wanting to know if I could have at least some cleaner LESS code :) Harry answered that for me below though. Using the ">" in this case would be correct if they were first-level children, but it is not always the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally not very comfortable with re-using class names like in your sample. However, re-using the selector in Less to achieve your expected output is fairly simple. You can use the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) (`&`) like in the below simplified example.

```
.r-slide-right-10 {
    color: red;
    & & {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

The above Less code when compiled would produce the following CSS.

```
.r-slide-right-10 {
  color: red;
}
.r-slide-right-10 .r-slide-right-10 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Whilst you're right about the parent selector, this won't alter the outputted CSS. I don't think it needs to be altered, just saying that this won't make a difference to the output :)

Comment: @mattytommo: You are correct. This would make no difference to the CSS but would make the Less code a bit more cleaner in my view. My answer was mainly for - *cleaner way to "re-use" the class selector?* :)

Comment: That's pretty much what I was asking for, cleaner code. This makes sense, I'm pretty new to the less CSS scene so I don't know all the selectors yet. I love it compared to ordinary CSS, I look back at doing CSS by hand in disgust now.

Comment: @MightyLampshade: Always happy to help. Don't feel bad about hand coding CSS, I would say it is always good that you know the base before using libraries to make coding simpler :)

Comment: It's given me a lot of enthusiasm for doing more responsive CSS, as I don't have to re-write the same gibberish 100 times with small differences.